# Heroku Permission denied. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github, ssh

So i have tried everything i can find and im panicing so please help
When i do a fresh heroku create on my app it genirates fine
then i go to git push heroku master.
I get the error

Jacks-MacBook-Air:morph jacksharville$ git push heroku master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

i have tried clear the keys with heroku keys:clear
I have then tried running heroku keys:add
It still comes up with the same error.

if i run ssh -vT git@heroku.com
this is the output

```
Jacks-MacBook-Air:morph jacksharville$ ssh -vT git@heroku.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.154] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/jacksharville/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/jacksharville/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jacksharville/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jacksharville/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version endosome
debug1: no match: endosome
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad
debug1: Host 'heroku.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/jacksharville/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/jacksharville/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to heroku.com ([194.168.4.123]:53).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
shell request failed on channel 0
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do `heroku auth:login` and then log in with your credentials?
Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Same error. Im defiantly logged in. I did do it again to make sure but it happened again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to fix this easily. The way i ended up getting around it is creating a new app and dragging assets across.